# What do the parentheses wrapping the object literal in an arrow function mean?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

I've seen JavaScript code such as this:

```
let a = () => ({ id: 'abc', name: 'xyz' })
```

What do the parentheses `( … )` wrapping the object refer to in this instance? Is it a shorthand for `return`?

Comment: A syntax error will be thrown without `()` surrounding `{ id: 'abc', name: 'xyz' }`,  `({ id: 'abc', name: 'xyz' })` is an expression

Comment: @xufox OPs title is poor. He's asking about the rhs wrapping parenths, not the parameterless lambda parenths on the lhs.

Comment: Because curly braces are used to denote the function’s body, an arrow function that wants to return an object literal outside of a function body must wrap the literal in parentheses. Found that info here: https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2013/09/10/understanding-ecmascript-6-arrow-functions/  ... down in the page before Usage.

Comment: Welcome to Ecmascript 2 0 1 5 !

Answer (score 58, accepted):

No. Those parentheses *produce* an object literal. [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) have many syntaxes, one of which is:

```
( … ) => expression
```

This will implicitly return an expression, for example:

```
() => 1 + 1
```

This function will implicitly return `1 + 1`, which is `2`. Another one is this:

```
( … ) => { … }
```

This will create a [block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block) to house multiple statements if you don't want to implicitly return an expression, and if you want to do intermediate calculations or not return a value at all. For example:

```
() => {
  const user = getUserFromDatabase();
  console.log(user.firstName, user.lastName);
}
```

The problem arises when you want to implicitly return an object literal. You can't use `( … ) => { … }` because it'll be interpreted as a block. The solution is to use parentheses.

The parentheses are there for the `{ … }` to be interpreted an object literal, not a block. In the [grouping operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Grouping), `( … )`, only expressions can exist within them. Blocks are not expressions but object literals *are*, thus an object literal is assumed. Thus, instead of creating a block, it will use this syntax:

```
( … ) => expression
```

And implicitly return an object literal. Without the parentheses, it will be interpreted as [labels](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) and strings, not keys and values of an object literal.

```
let a = () => { 
  id: 'abc', //interpreted as label with string then comma operator
  name: 'xyz' // interpreted as label (throws syntax error)
}
```

The comma here would be interpreted as the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator), and since the operands *must be expressions*, and labels are statements, it will throw a syntax error.

Comment: This answer is correct, except that I don't understand your statement that "Those parentheses also aren't wrapping an object literal, but *produce* an object literal." It seems to me that wrapping the object literal is *exactly* what the parentheses are doing. The object literal needs to be wrapped in parentheses for the reason you give in your answer.

Comment: @ruakh I know it's a bit late (a year late) but I didn't ever get around to editing this answer for some reason. I agree it is confusing. Removed the first clause.

Answer (score 12):

It allows you to create an *expression*, so

```
let a = () => ({ id: 'abc', name: 'xyz' })
```

specifies that `a` when invoked, returns the enclosed object

If you remove the `()` in this case, it will throw an error because it is not a valid function body statement, because the `{}` in `let a = () => { id: 'abc', name: 'xyz' }` are interpreted as the boundaries of a statement, but the content inside is not valid if you look at it.

```
let a = () => {
    id: 'abc',    /* Not valid JS syntax */
    name: 'xyz'
}
```

Comment: So is it correct to say that `let a = () => ({ id: 'abc', name: 'xyz' })` is the same as 
`let a = () => {return ({ id: 'abc', name: 'xyz' })}` and then also `let a = () => {return {id: 'abc', name: 'xyz' }}`?

Comment: @Mallory-Erik Yeep